# Creating multi dimensional array with array of keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create function which creates multidimensional array from parameter and second parameter should be saved as value here. Expected result is below:

```
Array
(
    [first] => Array
        (
            [second] => Array
                (
                    [last] => value
                )

        )

)
```

what I got so far :

```
 $array = ['first', 'second', 'last'];

    function multiArray($array, $newArray = [], $valueToSave)
    {
        if($array) {
            $value = current( $array );
            $key = array_search($value, $array);
            unset( $array[ $key ] );

            $newArray[$value] = [];
            return multiArray( $array, $newArray, $valueToSave);
        } else {
            return $newArray;
        }
    }
```

Any tips, what should I change or do next ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simplest one.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/873344)

```
$array = ['first', 'second', "third", "fourth",'last'];
$value = "someValue";

$result = array();
$count = count($array);
for($x=$count-1;$x>=0;$x--)
{
    if($x==$count-1):
        $result[$array[$x]]=$value;//setting value for last index
    else:
        $tempArray = $result;//storing value temporarily
        $result = array();//creating empty array
        $result[$array[$x]] = $tempArray;//overriting values.
    endif;
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.